# publishing android library to private maven repository on amazon s3

Tags: android, maven, amazon-s3, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I tried [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library) tutorial, when i run **gradlew publish**, it sending only pom and meta data but no aar file. Currently using gradle 2.10 and android version 2.1.0. Please suggest me any solution or working tutorial(tried a lot of tutorials/blogs).

And my basic understanding of the publishing on private maven repository is (Correct me if am wrong) : I publish it on S3 and with the provided URI and S3 credential developers(IDE) can directly fetch the aar file from the S3 repo.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Was this ever solved @Ravi ?

Comment: There is a nice [article](https://medium.com/@porten/publishing-android-library-artifacts-to-amazon-s3-buckets-8db4231e844f) on Medium. Good luck!